# GEKKO optimizer @error: Inequality Definition invalid inequalities: z > x < y

Tags: gekko

I am trying to solve a MINLP using the Gekko package.
A simple problem is shown below.

[the optimization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSFwU.png)

I wrote the code below but it gives me this error

@error: Inequality Definition
invalid inequalities: z > x < y

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

model = GEKKO()
model.options.SOLVER = 1

#define the inputs
R=[1000 for i in range(nflows)]
C=[[1000 for i in range(n_nodes)] for j in range(n_nodes)]


#define x_ij
x = [[model.Var(value=1, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True) for j in range(n_nodes)] for i in range(n_nodes)]
q = [[[model.Var(value=1/n_nodes, lb=0, ub=1, integer=False) for j in range(n_nodes)] for i in range(n_nodes)] for k in range(nflows)]


#define the objective
model.Obj(sum(sum((x[i][j] /(C[i][j] - R[k] * q[k][i][j] for k in range(nflows))) for j in range(n_nodes)) for i in range(n_nodes)))

n_const=0
for k in flows:
    for i in range(n_nodes):
        n_const += 1
        if checksource (i, k, flows):
            model.Equation(sum(x[i][j] * q[k][i][j] for j in range(n_nodes)) == 1)
        elif checkdest (i, k, flows):
            model.Equation(sum(x[j][i] * q[k][j][i] for j in range(n_nodes)) == 1)
        else:
            model.Equation(sum(x[i][j]*q[k][i][j] for j in range(n_nodes)) - sum(x[j][i] *q[k][j][i] for j in range(n_nodes)) == 0)

model.solve()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues with your current model. Here is a fix for your variable declaration and objective function that is easier to configure and read.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO

nflows = 2
n_nodes = 2

model = GEKKO(remote=False)
model.options.SOLVER = 1

#define the inputs
R=[1000 for i in range(nflows)]
C=[[1000 for i in range(n_nodes)] for j in range(n_nodes)]


#define x_ij
x = model.Array(model.Var,(n_nodes,n_nodes),lb=0,ub=1)
q = model.Array(model.Var,(n_nodes,n_nodes,nflows),value=1/n_nodes,lb=0,ub=1)

#define the objective
for i in range(n_nodes):
    for j in range(n_nodes):
        for k in range(nflows):
            model.Minimize(x[i,j] /(C[i][j] - R[k] * q[k][i][j]))
            
model.solve()
```

You'll need to add the constraints but hopefully this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you John for your support. I have another question.   I tried to set x[i,i]=0 as a constant in the problem which is to avoid solve loops. But it gives the error z>x<y.   is there another way to control these variables

Comment: If it is a variable then you can add an equation as `m.Equation(x[i,i]==0)`. You can't redefine a Variable as a constant. If you want to eliminate simple equations such as that from the problem before it gets to the solver then use `m.options.REDUCE=1`. This can speed up your problem if it is taking a long time to solve.

Comment: This is what I did, added new constraints to restrict these variables to 0.   These constraints resulted in  error z>x<y

Comment: You can open your run directory and look at the `apm` model file that it is creating with `m.open_folder()`. Open the `gk_model0.apm` file in a text editor to see what is causing the error.